# Killing vector field in terms of the tetrad basis

Tags: general-relativity, mathematical-physics

I have come across the following equations in Wald. For a static spherically symmetry metric
$$ds^2 = -f(r)dt^2 + h(r)dr^2 + r^2 ( d{\theta^2} \sin^2{\theta}d{\phi^2})$$. 
If $(e_{\mu})_a$ are the basis vectors of the orthogonal tetrad system, and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ are the killing vectors corresponding to transformations of $t$ and $r$ then
$$1. \,\, (e_0)_a=f^{\frac{1}{2}}(dt)_a=f^{-\frac{1}{2}} (\frac{\partial}{\partial t})_a$$
$$2. \,\, (e_1)_a=h^{\frac{1}{2}}(dr)_a=h^{-\frac{1}{2}} (\frac{\partial}{\partial r})_a $$
The first equality of each of the equation is clear to me, but how do you related th killing vector to the tetrad basis vector? (i.e. how do I get the second equality of each of the equations)

Comment: In the second equalities you are just using the metric to lower indices and thus take $dt\rightarrow f^{-1} \partial_t$ for example in (1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a semi-Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, there is a canonical isomorphism between the tangent and cotangent spaces at a given point which we, as physicists, commonly refer to as "raising and lower indices."

In coordinates this isomorphism works as follows.  If $X$ is a tangent vector at a point $p\in M$, then it can be written in components as
$$
  X = X^a \partial_a
$$
Now we define lowered components
$$
  X_a = g_{ab}X^b
$$
and define a one-form $\mathbf X$ by
$$
  \mathbf X = X_a dx^a
$$
Then the mapping $X \mapsto \mathbf X$ is an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $T_p^*M$.  In the case you wrote down we would have
$$
  e_0 = (e_0)^a\partial_a = (e_0)^t\partial_t
$$
and the dual one-form is
$$
  \mathbf e_0 = (e_0)_adx^a = (e_0)_tdt
$$
where
$$
  (e_0)^t = g^{ta}(e_0)_a = g^{tt}(e_0)_t = -f^{-1}(e_0)_t
$$
Specifically, if $(e_0)_t = f^{1/2}$, then its dual component is $(e_0)^t=-f^{-1/2}$.

Comment: +1 : With the OP presentation, $(dt)_a = g_{ab} (\frac{\partial}{\partial t})^b$, and $(dr)_a = g_{ab} (\frac{\partial}{\partial r})^b$. The OP notations $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})_a$ and $(\frac{\partial}{\partial r})_a$ are incorrect. Vectors have upper indice coordinates $\large \frac{\partial}{\partial t} =(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})^a \frac{\partial}{\partial x^a} $, while 1-forms have lower indice coordinates $dt = (dt)_a dx^a$

Comment: @Josh: Thanks a lot! But are we not here, equating the vectors in two different vector spaces (the tangent and the cotangent)? How is this possible?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac We are not actually *equating* vectors in these two spaces, we are merely *identifying* them with one another since we have an isomorphism between these two vector spaces.  If you ever write an equality in which you have a one-form on one side, and a tangent vector field on the other, then you have, strictly speaking, made a mistake.  Notice that I never write equalities like this in my answer.